# Odds of drawing multiple rounds of rock paper scissors.

Tags: probability

OK, so the back story for this is me and my friend often decide things on a quick game of rock paper scissors. I think on this occasion it was for who would get up and answer the door when the pizza came. The point is, on this occasion, we drew 17 times in a row before we broke the dead lock.

How do I find the odds of drawing n games of rock, paper, scissors?

We were playing the normal rules of rock, paper, scissors and, for arguments sake, there were no tactics or mind games going on - just random choices by both my friend and I (though I think some kind of subconscious thing must have been at play because my gut tells me the odds of this are astronomical).

Comment: In any one round P(win) = P(loss) = P(draw) = 1/3. If you believe $n$ successive rounds are independent, then the probability of drawing $n$ times is $1/3^n$. For $n = 17$ that is highly unlikely!

Comment: About $1$ in $129$ million. If everyone in the world paired up to play a game of r-p-s ($\sim 3.62$ billion matches), only $\sim 28$ matches or so would run at least this long.

Comment: For real life players the assumption of independence may not be justified, however. Once both picked paper thrice, say, they may *both* try to outwit each other with the same ideas ("Now he'll think I take paper again and takes scissors; hence I take rock") and draws continue with higher than usual probability.

Comment: I'd agree, there must have been something like that going on - though I imagine, even taking this into account, the odds were high for 17 in a row. My other friend, who was also present, flat out wouldn't believe that my friend and I hadn't staged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances of a draw when both parties chosing uniformly are exactly $\frac13$ (it's a fair game because of this). Now for that to happen $17$ times in a row, the chances are
$$\frac1{3^{17}} \approx 7.74\cdot 10^{-9}$$
but keep in mind that these are a-priori. That means for example after two draws, the chances of another draw stay at $\frac13$ and the chances for the $15$ remaining draws consecutively are $\frac1{3^{15}}$.